# How to write to serial log in boot diagnostics in azure from VM?

Tags: c, azure, serial-port, azure-virtual-machine, serial-communication

I tried writing to COM2 port (which was the only available port in mode) like this:

```
#define diagnose_general(c,a, ...)(printf("%s - "c"\n", #a, a(__VA_ARGS__)))
#define diagnose(a, ...)diagnose_general("%lx",a,__VA_ARGS__)

#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>


main() {FILE *fserial;
diagnose_general("%p",fserial=fopen, "COM2", "w");

diagnose(fprintf,fserial,"\n\nthread %lx:\n", GetCurrentThreadId());
diagnose_general("%zx",fwrite,"test",sizeof "test",1,fserial);
diagnose(fflush,fserial);
diagnose(fclose,fserial);}
```

It succeseeds but nothing new is shown in the boot diagnostics Serial log window in the portal. Any ideas?

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding 1)  follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2)  do not try to hide the code via some macros

Comment: OT: regarding: `main()`  regardless of what visual studio allows, there are only two valid signatures for `main()`  They are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`

Comment: OT: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call `perror( "your error message" );` to output both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`.

Comment: regarding: `diagnose(fprintf,fserial,"\n\nthread %lx:\n", GetCurrentThreadId());`  Since no thread has been started (perhaps via a call to `pthread_create()` it is doubtful that `GetCurrentThreadId()` would return anything useful and normally the returned value would be a `pthread_t`, Such a returned value is unlikely to be a match for a format specifier of `%lx`

Answer (score 0):

I did this recently. I had to write to COM1, not COM2. Are you sure your VM does not have COM1 defined? Can you add it?